# Why is the pattern of full decay widths of $\Upsilon(1S)–(2S)–(3S)$ mesons inverted?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

[Upsilon mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsilon_meson) are bound states of b-quark and anti-b-quark, of $J^{PC} = 1^{– –}$. First three states are located below $B\bar{B}$ threshold so they decay either via [OZI-suppressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OZI_rule) strong transitions to light hadrons, or via electromagnetic transitions (dilepton decays, etc). Notably, they can also decay to lower bottomonium states, for example, $\Upsilon(2S)$ can decay to $\Upsilon(1S) \pi \pi$.

There is apparently nothing which is different for these states, except that with their mass getting larger, more decay channels open up. Therefore, naively, I would expect that the first state, $\Upsilon(1S)$, should be the narrowest of all them (in other words, should have the longest lifetime), while the width of the $\Upsilon(2S)$ should be larger, and that of the $\Upsilon(3S)$ larger again.

This assumption, however, seems to contradict to the experimental data from the [PDG](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/tables/rpp2020-tab-mesons-b-bbar.pdf):

| Particle | Mass (MeV) | Full width (keV) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\Upsilon(1S)$ | 9460.30±0.26 | 54.02±1.25 |
| $\Upsilon(2S)$ | 10023.26±0.31 | 31.98±2.63 |
| $\Upsilon(3S)$ | 10355.2±0.5 | 20.32±1.85 |

So, the higher-mass states actually get **narrower**, which looks counter-intuitive!
This controversy is absent in the charmonium system:

| Particle | Mass (MeV) | Full width (keV) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $J/\psi(1S)$ | 3096.900±0.006 | 92.9±2.8 |
| $\psi(2S)$ | 3686.10±0.06 | 294±8 |

where the second state is wider that the first state, as expected. (The third one is above the $D\bar{D}$ threshold so useless for this discussion.)

**Question**: What is the reason for such inverted behavior of the Upsilon system?

My hypothesis was falling back to the OZI rule, predicting that higher-mass mesons would annihilate into gluons of higher energy, which end up having lower running coupling constant $\alpha_s$ (the general trend that Upsilons are narrower the Psi's could point in this direction, too). This would however not explain why the effect is absent in the charmonium system; and why the presence of decays to lower $b\bar{b}$ resonances does not compensate for that effect.

[I tried to search for papers on the topic, but found only discussions of the dielectron decay width (not the full one), or of the higher states above the $B\bar{B}$ threshold.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is misleading to look at the total width, because the breakdown into partial widths is quite different.

One thing to compare is the $3g$ width (basically the total hadronic width). According to PDG
$$
\Gamma(\psi(2s),3g)=299 keV\cdot 10\% = 30 keV 
$$
$$
\Gamma(J/\psi(1s),3g)=93 keV\cdot 66\% = 60 keV 
$$
The same pattern is seen in Upsilon states
$$
\Gamma(\Upsilon(3s),3g)=20 keV\cdot 36\% = 7.2 keV 
$$
$$
\Gamma(\Upsilon(2s),3g)=32 keV\cdot 59\% = 19.2 keV 
$$
$$
\Gamma(\Upsilon(1s),3g)=54 keV\cdot ?\% = ?
$$
I'm not sure why PDG does not attempt to give a $3g$ width for the $1s$ Upsilon. The results seem consistent with the perturbative estimate $\Gamma\sim \alpha_s^3 |\psi_n(0)|^2$ which we expect to be smaller for larger $n$ because the wave function at the origin is smaller.

What increases the total $\psi(2s)$ width is a large branching ratio into $J/\psi (\pi\pi)$.  This is a different kind of decay, governed by non-perturbative QCD multipole transition. There is some theory for these transitions, see, for example, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5827). I'm not an expert, but it makes sense to me that the corresponding matrix elements would be larger in the $J/\psi$ compared to the $\Upsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on the "we expect to be smaller for larger  because the wave function at the origin is smaller" argument?

Comment: Higher radial wave functions are more extended, so the wave function at the origin is smaller. For the Coulomb problem $\psi_n(0)|^2$ can be found in QM text books.